# setting up a MEAN app in production

Tags: node.js, apache, express, centos6, mean-stack

I am a frontend developer and having issues setting up my MEAN app in production server. I am confused about the role of apache ? if any.

right now I don't have a domain name, just an IP address for a CentOS 6 VPS.

I stopped apache and am using express only, I deployed the app code and ran the grunt task in production environment and the app is listening on port 3000 .. but when I visit the site at 
http://104.238.103.223:3000/ I get a **"page not available"** error

I am confused at how to specify a "DocumentRoot" without apache ? how do I tell DNS where to find my app ? I may be looking at the problem wrong since I am not well aware of the backend side of things.

Comment: It depends. You can skip apache all together and use node.js in place of it if you want. Typically though you'll use something like apache or nginx and do a reverse proxy to the node server, but still use apache or nginx to serve the static html js and css files because apache and nginx are typically better for that purpose.

Comment: Did you opened the port 3000 in firewall ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should reverse proxy to port 80 (or 443 for https) to access your application with your domain name. You can use apache, nginx or haproxy etc.

Also check your firewall if port 3000 is allowed.

Check out this page; http://blog.podrezo.com/making-node-js-work-with-apache/

Comment: Thanks adding a reverse proxy and running apache along with Node.JS worked !